# How to create histogram that overlay by category variable?

Tags: python, histogram, overlay

Suppose I have a data like this.

```
Gender  Age =>
Male    50,
Female  40,
Female  35,
Male    45,
Female  30,
...
```

I want to write python code to produce Age histogram that overlay by Gender.
How can I do that ?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Did you perform any research to find possible solutions? Stack Overflow is not a code generator!

Comment: Sorry guy, I tried to find what I looking for in google before I post here. But I found only case that the overlay came from 2 columns.